# Redirect to page before login

Tags: ruby-on-rails

right now I have a problem with login. I want the user to go the previous page where he/she pressed the login-button. In my code right now I just have redirect_to back which just sends the user back one level but I want it to be two levels. How do I do that?

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
    def new
    end

    def create
        user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
        if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
            sign_in user
            redirect_to back
        else
            flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def destroy
        sign_out
        redirect_to root_url
    end

end
```

Thanks!

Comment: If no one is able to give you a "Rails Way" answer you could hack around this with javascript: [javascript history methods](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_his_back.asp)

Comment: Thanks auL5agoi, it will be my last resort :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one of the solution maybe store the url inside the cookies, and redirect to that url after sign in

```
cookies[:return_to] = {
  value: request.fullpath, 
  expires: 1.hour.from_now
}

redirect_to sign_in_path
```

after login, just call

```
path = cookies[:return_to]
cookies.delete(:return_to)
redirect_to path
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked with a little edit. Did request.referer instead since I had login at multiple places.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to probably follow the [outline that the devise gem provides](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-back-to-current-page-after-sign-in,-sign-out,-sign-up,-update) in their how-to.  TL;DR - store the path in the session and use that as your redirect after sign in.

Comment: Thanks, not using devise though so unsure if I can use it but thanks anyway!

Comment: Devise won't matter - it's the concept of storing the path in the session.